# Get listview item from image click (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have a listview where each row has few images and some text blocks.
If I use **ItemClick** event for ListView, I can easily get the clicked item (binded object) using something like this:

```
private void MainListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var device = (Device)e.ClickedItem;
    }
```

But I want to distinguish between clicks on different elements (images) within the ListView row. So I use **Tapped** event for ImageView (which is inside ListView) where event handler looks like this:

```
private void image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How can I get the clicked ListView item in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the item from the data context of the tapped element

```
var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
var device = fe.DataContext as Device;
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.